# Square that fills according to the origin of the pointer

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm requesting help for something I thought was easier to code.
I would like to code a square that "fills" gradually (like a bucket or a bathtub..but without gravity!) when the pointer hovers it and according to the direction of the pointer. That is, if the pointer comes from the right of the square, the color fills it from right to left, if it comes from the bottom, the color fills it from the bottom to the top...etc.

This is a code that fills my square in any direction but only if i change some properties. This is this code:

```
    <div class="square" ></div>

  <style>::after
   .square {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    
    position: relative;

  }
  
  .square::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(#3498db, #3498db);
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transform: scaleY(0); 

    transition: transform 0.5s ease; 
}

  
  .square:hover::before {
    transform: scaleY(1); 
    
  }
  </style>
```

Here, the color fills the square from bottom to top. By modifying transform-origin: bottom with transform-origin: top ,it will go from top to bottom. The same with left and right AND replaceing the two scaleY by scaleX, itl will go from left to right or right to end?

But how to combine this code with someting (I suppose in javascript) that will indicate the origine of the pointer so that the color automatically fills the square in the direction of the pointer?

Thank you for helping a beginner!

Didier

Answer (score 0):

```js
const square = document.getElementById("square");
const el = document.getElementsByClassName("collision");

el[0].addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
  square.style.transform = `rotate(180deg)`;
});

el[1].addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
  square.style.transform = `rotate(90deg)`;
});

el[2].addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
  square.style.transform = `rotate(0deg)`;
});

el[3].addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
  square.style.transform = `rotate(270deg)`;
});
```

```css
.square,
.square2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.collision:nth-child(odd) {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.collision:nth-child(even) {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.collision:nth-child(1) {
  top: -20px;
}

.collision:nth-child(2) {
  left: -20px;
}

.collision:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: -20px;
}

.collision:nth-child(4) {
  right: -20px;
}

.square::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#3498db, #3498db);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.square:hover::before {
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="square2">
  <div class="collision"></div>
  <div class="collision"></div>
  <div class="collision"></div>
  <div class="collision"></div>
</div>
<div class="square" id="square"></div>
```

This code works as you said, but if you move too fast, it works strangely...
I implement your request by adding collision box to square.

Comment: Thank tou very much! The fillings are perfetct! Il will study your solution to fully understand it ! I am very grateful . You solved my problem and taught me this approach!